# What adaptations would allow a being to live in tritiated water?

Tags: biology, evolution, xenobiology, radioactivity

I am interested in having the monster of the week for an episode/arc be a creature that lives in a stream of [tritiated water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tritiated_water) (T<sub>2</sub>O).

The said creature is a colony of microorganisms that have evolved from exposure to the water to be able to go onto land and attack people. How realistic would that be, and what kinds of adaptations would an organism that lives in tritiated water need in order to live there long term?

Comment: Hi. Related post here: [Life and heavy water](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/33923/55743). Could you give us some more details, such as tritium concentration (and deuterium too), the nature of the life (eg. carbon-based, silicon-based, phosphorous/sulphur based etc). Do they make use of water in metabolism?

Comment: Just to add, you don't expect their metabolism/movement to be fast do you? Could be tricky.

Comment: What is the concentration of tritiated water? Are we talking about pure $T_{2}O$ or will there also be $H_{2}O$ or $HTO$? What kind of life are we talking about?

Comment: Where does the tritium come from? With a half-life of 12 years it must be continually being replenished, and there’s a shortage of plausible natural processes that could do so.

Comment: It's not really possible. If your creature is of human scale, then a mere m^3 of water for your creature to live in would output over 81kW(!) of heat from radiation alone (the water would also boil away in couple of hours). Aside from that, the T2O would self-radiolyze itself away to nothingness.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [bacterium that lives exclusively off radioactivity](https://www.sciencealert.com/bacterium-lives-off-nuclear-energy-alien-life-europa#)

There are some organic chemical reactions that prefer deuterium to hydrogen. The aldol condensation preferentially substitutes deuterium for hydrogen. But this is so slow that it is not a commercial process. Tritium would probably decay faster than this would concentrate it.

The bacterium has an extremely slow metabolism. Anything larger, or faster probably find radioactivity does more harm to it than good. Don't sweat it: I believe Godzilla films have made money.

Answer (score 4):

A coordinated colony would be very unrealistic. Not a single example of a colony of microorganisms demonstrating such complex behavior exists.

Evolution is a process that takes millions of years of relatively stable environment and significant population. E.g. islands isolated from continents likely to have their own animal species evolved but almost never their own fresh water fish because rivers and lakes are not big and stable enough. Tritiated water would have the same problem multiplied by general hostility of this environment to life.

For complex behavior to evolve there must be long history of beneficial mutations where colony becomes more and more proficient in "going onto land and attacking" something. And as soon as colony start going out, why would it ever return to this tritiated water? It most certainly not a beneficial environment and normal water is everywhere.

That said, evolution is abused in fiction for so long that people would likely just accept it.

Comment: Just like we can't live on highly titrated water maybe the creature's metabolic properties are engineered to work with it--it can't live with normal water.